# Списки, указатели и динамическая память в Pascal

Tags: pascal

Задали задачу на паскаль:
Смоделировать работу фотоателье, обслуживающего репортеров, фотографов и папарацци, причем папарацци обслуживаются в последнюю очередь. При подготовке фотографий расходуются ресурсы в необходимом количестве. Как ресурсы закончатся, обслуживание приостанавливается до поступления новых ресурсов, при этом есть резерв, которым можно воспользоваться для обслуживания репортеров. В любой момент должна быть доступна информация о имеющихся ресурсах и не обслуженных клиентов в очереди.

Вопрос собственно не в построении программы, а в отдельных частях ее, а именно программа закрывается с ошибкой - "» Непредвиденное исключение EAccessViolation. Access violation at address 0075CD31 in module 'PascalABC.exe'. Read of address 00003288. Программа завершена (photo.pas, строка 45)"

Программа еще далеко не полная, но уже вогнала меня в тупик, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, в чем мои ошибки.

Вот код:

```
program photo;

uses crt, timers;

type ukazatel = ^elem_spiska;
     elem_spiska = record
                 znach : Integer;
                 next : ukazatel;
     end;

var
   reporter, photographer, paparazzi, rand, i, resources, rezerv, m: integer;
   head, p, q : ukazatel;

{процедура обслуживания}
procedure service;
begin
     if resources = 0 then
        begin
             p := head;                      {начать с головы списка}
             while p^.next^.znach <> 2 do
                   p := p^.next;
             q := p^.next;        {удаляемый элемент}
             p^.next := q^.next;  {связка «через один»}
             dispose(q);
             rezerv := rezerv - 1;
        end
     else
         begin
              p := p^.next;   {переход к следующему элементу списка}
              resources := resources - 1;
         end;
end;
{процедура добавления очереди}
procedure turn;
var t, o: integer;
begin
     t := Random(3)+0;
     writeln(t);
     p := head^.next;
     if p = nil then
        begin
             new(p);
             p^.znach := t;
             p^.next := nil;
        end
     else if (p^.znach = 0) and (t > 0) then
             begin
                  p^.znach := t;
                  p^.next^.znach := 0;
                  p^.next^.next := nil;
             end
          else
              begin
                   new(q);
                   q := p^.next;
                   q^.znach := t;
                   p^ := q^;
                   dispose(q);
              end;
end;
{процедура запуска обслуживания}
procedure open_service;
var u: integer;
begin
     u := 1;
     new(p);
     new(q);
     new(head);
     head^.znach := u;
     randomize;
     reporter := 2;
     photographer := 1;
     paparazzi := 0;
     resources := 100;
     rezerv := 100;
     while rezerv > 0 do
           begin
                turn;
                writeln(p^.znach);
                sleep(1000);
                turn;
                sleep(1000);
                writeln(p^.znach);
                service;
                sleep(1500);
           end;

end;
begin
     WriteLn('Фото Ателье');
     writeln('1 - открыть заведение');
     writeln('2 - Закрыть заведение');
     read(m);
     case m of
          1: open_service;
          0: exit;
     end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первоначально должна быть пустая очередь, т.е. вместо

```
 new(p);
 new(q);
 new(head);
```

должно быть

```
p:=nil;
q:=nil;
head:=nil;
```

а выделение памяти должно быть при добавлении каждого нового элемента внутри процедуры turn.

По поводу ошибки:

```
 p := head^.next;
 if p = nil then
    begin
         p^.znach := t;
         p^.next := nil;
    end
```

данные пишутся по пустому указателю. Думаю что после begin нужно сделать new(p). С учетом того, что первоначально очередь пустая:

```
 p := head;
 if p = nil then
    begin
        new(p);
         p^.znach := t;
         p^.next := nil;
    end
```

**UPD.** Вот что у меня получилось:

```
{...}
{процедура обслуживания}
procedure service(var p:ukazatel);
var temp:ukazatel;
begin
  if p <> nil then
     if resources = 0 then
        begin
          if p^.znach = 2 then {если первый элемент - тот что нам нужен}
          begin
            q := p^.next; {запоминаем следующий элемент}
            dispose(p); {освобождаем первый элемент}
            p := q; {перенаправляем указатели}
            rezerv := rezerv - 1;
          end
          else begin
            q := p^.next;
            {цикл пока не достигнем конца или пока не найдем:}
            while (q^.next <> nil) and (q^.next^.znach <> 2) do 
              q := q^.next;

            if q^.next <> nil then {если это не конец списка, то}
            begin
              temp:=q^.next; {временно сохраняем указатель на удаляемый элемент}
              q^.next := temp^.next; {перенаправляем связи}
              dispose(temp); {освобождаем удаляемый элемент}
              rezerv := rezerv - 1;
            end;
          end;
        end
     else
         begin
            q := p^.next; {запоминаем следующий элемент}
            dispose(p); {освобождаем текущий элемент}
            p := q; {переход к следующему элементу списка}
            resources := resources - 1;
         end;
end;
{процедура добавления очереди}
procedure turn(var p:ukazatel);
var t, o: integer;
begin
     t := Random(3);
     writeln(t);
     if p = nil then {пустая очередь}
        begin
             new(p);
             p^.znach := t;
             p^.next := nil;
        end
     else if t > 0 then
             begin {добавление в начало списка}
                new(q);
                q^.znach := t;
                q^.next := p;
                p := q;
             end
          else
              begin {добавление вторым элементом списка}
                   new(q);
                   q^.znach := t;
                   q^.next := p^.next;
                   p^.next := q;
              end;
end;

{процедура запуска обслуживания}
procedure open_service;
var u: integer;
begin
     head:=nil; {пустой список}
     randomize;
     reporter := 2;
     photographer := 1;
     paparazzi := 0;
     resources := 100;
     rezerv := 100;
     while rezerv > 0 do
           begin
                turn(head);
                writeln(head^.znach);
                sleep(1000);
                turn(head);
                sleep(1000);
                writeln(head^.znach);
                service(head);
                sleep(1500);
           end;
end;
{...}
```

Вообще советую почитать про работу со списками, вот тут например: [Фундаментальные алгоритмы и структуры данных в Delphi](http://sdb.su/programmirovanie/delphi/page,2,239-fundamentalnye-algoritmy-i-struktury-dannyx-v-delphi-chast-3-iz-14.html). Все то же самое должно работать и на PascalABC.

P.S. Только это получилась не очередь, а стек. Чтобы получилась очередь, нужно добавлять в конец списка, а забирать из начала.

Comment: спасибо, поправил.
но ошибка возникает ниже, а как мне видно на первом else(после if p = nil) 
так что проблема осталась :(

Comment: Вопрос: указатели p, q и head - для чего используется каждый из них?

Comment: ну вроде как head это голова динамического списка(всегда должен показывать на первый элемент списка - я же очередь в ателье выстраиваю), p - все последующие элементы и q - для удаления из середины и связки через один.

Comment: вот это хорошо. Спасибо, insolor.
Думаю, с очередью я теперь разберусь сам(хотя бы попробую)